# SSL certificates authentification at ASP.NET. Force IE ask certificate after user press cancel

Tags: authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm creating SSL authentification using ASP.NET. What users launches the site we see a window for certificates selection (IIS configured to accept user certificates). It look like this.

[image]

We have 2 buttons here: OK and Cancel. After user click OK I get some info from certificate and make authentification.

At next page user can make some activities or press button to change user. Here is webforms button code

```
<asp:Image runat="server" src="img/btnChangeUser.jpg" Style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache'); document.location.reload(true); return false;"
                                    ID="Image1"></asp:Image>
```

If user wants to use other certificate onclick javascript section works perfect

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache'); 
document.location.reload(true);
```

We clear SSL state and reload page. But if user press cancel at next page I need to tell him that there are impossible to use web site without certificate and add button what will opens this window again for certificate selection.
Unfortunately the same code as for certificate change does not work. Do you have any ideas why? How can I use javascript to make site work after user presses cancel?
Page refresh do nopt work and window do not appear even if I clean ClearAuthenticationCache.